# В чем причина некорректной работы скрипта

Tags: скрипт, mikrotik

```
:global myTest do={:return  (/interface ethernet disable ether5)}
```

Данная функция не выполняется при ее вызове. В чём может быть проблема?

Вот что в переменной происходит:

```
[admin@MikroTik] > :put $myTest                                                   
;(eval (eval /returnvalue=(  $/interface $ethernet $disable $ether5)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

комманды CLI надо брать в квадратные скобки -

```
:global myTest do={:return  ([/interface ethernet disable ether5])}
```

так как команда одна и неделима то можно и без круглых скобок

```
:global myTest do={:return [/interface ethernet disable ether5]}
```

весьма маловероятно что он сможет что-то вернуть, поэтому можно сократить до

```
:global myTest do={[/interface ethernet disable ether5]}
```

чтобы он сработал не надо вызывать `[admin@MikroTik] > :put $myTest`
достаточно `[admin@MikroTik] > $myTest`